# UILabel custom fonts works only on iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, uifont

i am subclassing a `UILabel` to set a custom font so i can use it across header bars in my app. so i have created a `HeaderLabel` class that inherit from `UILabel` and i have added this code to set the font :

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
       if (self) {

       self.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"fbTypoPas-Black" size:34];
       self.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
    return self;
}
```

i am not holding any reference to the`HeaderLabel`  from `IB` just setting the text i want.
it works well on `IOS` 7, `IOS` 6 and 5 not seem to be working

[image]

Comment: Add font and textColor to the drawRect method.

Comment: nothing is working, it just disappeared

Comment: Add a breakpoint to if (self) { }, see if it goes in there.

Comment: it is go in the breakpoint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like that:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if (self) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            self.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"fbTypoPas-Black" size:34];
            self.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        });
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it in `-(void)awakeFromNib`, but don't forget to call `[super awakeFromNib]` !

Comment: i think the problem is with the font... i tried to use other font in ios 6 and it works

Comment: here are the fonts, thanks!
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/7kr31b3urbx8z7o/6DTtnh1igy

Comment: Thanks. How do you import them into Xcode, how do you add them to the info.plist, and how are they named as UIFonts?

Comment: i have copied the fonts to the projects, i can see then in the copy bundle resources section. in the info.plist i created "Fonts provided by application" entry as array with 2 strings items named : FbTypoPas-Black.otf , FbTypoPas-Regular.otf and i am creating uifont object like this :        self.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"fbTypoPas-Black" size:34];
 from uilabel subclass. just to remind, it works on ios 7